# Set dimensions of OpenLayers map container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, openlayers

I have basic HTML layout with Bootstrap navbar and an OpenLayers map.

[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mleontenko/6sfugnd7/).

HTML looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

The problem is navbar because it pushes the map div down and i have to scroll down a bit to see the whole map. Can I somehow restrict the map to fit only the visible screen extents so i don't get any scrolling space (like in the picture below)?

[image]

Here is a good example of what i'm trying to acomplish:
http://jumpinjackie.github.io/bootstrap-viewer-template/2-column/index.html

Comment: Add this style : .map{
  overflow:hidden;
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add:

```
#map {
  height: calc(100vh - 52px); /* 100% of the viewport height - navbar height */
}
```

Comment: This solved it, thanks! Is navbar height always 52px? Will this work on mobile?

Comment: No problem, glad it did, it will work all the time, I think it stays at 52px.

Comment: If you see any difference or if the navbar height changes (though I think it won't), find out how much is it (right click on the element & inspect element) and simply add this rule to the media query where the break happens: #map {height: calc(100vh - new inspected height of the navbar in px);}