# Map keeps overflowing the bottom of the page

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to make my openlayers map fill the screen. The problem is that it keeps scaling with a fixed ratio.

[image: why this ratio?]

When the screen becomes wide enough it overflow and scrollbars appear.

[image: scrollbars]

I can fix this by using a fixed position but then my attribution and scaling bar disappears. Any idea why it is not sizing to the screen correctly?

[image: No attibution button!]

Answer (score 0):

found the solution here:
[Set dimensions of OpenLayers map container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413436/set-dimensions-of-openlayers-map-container)

So the bootstrap nav bar was pushing it down and the map had to be adjusted to fill the height.